# signature_invalid LinkedIn

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to get access token from [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?) I am passing All parameters correct but the error 401-invalid signature is still there
code is

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?
        oauth_consumer_key=d84z39zfvu1e&
        oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
        oauth_signature=Z8CFWW1i0mvcW8g6CiY%2BqL%2BfOik%3D&
        oauth_timestamp=1330086574&
        oauth_nonce=2222&
        oauth_version=1.0&
        callback=http://localhost:8080/linkedIn/">
```

Comment: What language and library are you using?  OAuth is pretty tricky if you're just trying to get it going from scratch.  Have you checked your signature against the OAuth test console at http://developer.linked.com/oauth-test-console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the request token you are trying to get. A common mistake when getting the request token is using the wrong key when signing the request.

Your HMAC-SHA1 key when signing all requests should look like this:

`CONSUMER_SECRET + "&" + TOKEN_SECRET`

And since you do not have a token secret yet, the key should be `CONSUMER_SECRET + "&"`